# Click to drop widget using gwt-dnd library

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I'm using gwt-dnd library and I would like to know how to make click to drop.
That is, click the widget to move, release the mouse button, drag the widget and click to drop.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know your use case. But this seems counter intuitive to what users expect about drag-n-drop, which I would not recommend to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty big hacking. gwt-dnd handles mouse events by  MouseDragHandler class and it's tightly coupled with AbstractDragController, so you must provide your own implementation of this handler (just extend it) which will call onMouseDown and onMouseUp methods on your click events. But you must also override AbstractDragController, so you end up rewriting half of the library.